# How do I import FileNotFoundError from Python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, python-3.x

I am currently using Python 2 on a project that needs a Python 3 built-in exception: `FileNotFoundError`. How do I do it?

Comment: You can't do that. Why not just define the exception yourself?

Comment: `try` then `except:pass`

Comment: @Hackaholic Err... no. Why would he want to do that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can of course define any exceptions you want.

But they're not going to do you any good. The whole point of `FileNotFoundError` is that any Python operation that runs into a file-not-found error will raise that exception. Just defining your own exception won't make that true. All you're going to get is an `OSError` (or `IOError`, depending on 2.x version) with an appropriate `errno` value. If you try to handle a custom `FileNotFoundError`, your handler will never get called.

So, what you really want is (for example):

```
try:
    f = open(path)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
        # do your FileNotFoundError code here
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: Seems like the [correct exception is IOError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IOError).

Comment: @Mansour: for 2.6-2.7, the two are pretty cleanly divided. For older versions (especially if you're not using CPython), it's a different story (and some things, like socket connect errors, were _neither_). Hence "depending on 2.x version". To be safe, you can always catch both, or (unless you need to go way back to 1.5) their common subclass EnvironmentError.

Comment: So, if it "depends on 2.x version", and the developer doesn't know which 2.x version to expect, then they should just catch an `EnvironmentError` with `errno.ENOENT`.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`IOError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IOError) instead:

> Raised when an I/O operation (such as a print statement, the built-in open() function or a method of a file object) fails for an I/O-related reason, **e.g., “file not found”** or “disk full”.
>
> This class is derived from EnvironmentError. See the discussion above for more information on exception instance attributes.
>
> Changed in version 2.6: Changed socket.error to use this as a base class.

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Usually, one sentence answers aren't sufficient on SO.

Comment: A link or quote to the documentation, would be great.  ^^ That's much more inclusive +1

Comment: I've added the quote. and highlighted the "file not found" part :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create the `FileNotFoundError` exception yourself:

```
class FileNotFoundError(OSError):
    pass
```

This new exception class inherits from `OSError` just like the one in Python 3.x.

Here is a reference on [User-defined Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#tut-userexceptions) in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  **Just use `EnvironmentError` and check `err.errno == errno.ENOENT` for either Python 2 or Python 3.**

Long answer:

As other answers have mentioned, `FileNotFoundError` is new to Python 3.

Python 2 used `OSError` (or `IOError`, depending on 2.x version).  `OSError` and `IOError` both inherit from `EnvironmentError`.

In Python 3, `EnvironmentError` is aliased to `OSError`.  `FileNotFoundError` inherits from `OSError`, which means that `FileNotFoundError` can be caught with `EnvironmentError`, and it shares the same interface as `OSError` and `IOError`.

So, good news!  This means that there is a relatively easy way to make your project compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3 at the same time: leave `FileNotFoundError` out of it, and just catch `EnvironmentError`.

```
# Works for Python 2.  Also works for Python 3.
import errno

try:
    open("fake.file", 'r')
except EnvironmentError as err:
    if err.errno == errno.ENOENT: # ENOENT -> "no entity" -> "file not found"
        print("Caught 'file not found' exception")
    else:
        raise
```