# How to properly raise a file exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below requirements:

1. Read the files from Directory, need to find files with wildcard search as there are lot of files in the directory.
2. If file pattern doesn't match, then I need to raise an exception. Please look at the code below. I am struggling with exception.

I am able to search the files with `fnmatch` function but if file doesn't exist, then I am am struggling with exception. How do I add exception? Please look at the `readstatus()` function and please help me how do I add exception logic if file does not exist.

```
import os
import sys
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
import configparser
import re
import os.path
import glob
import aws_encryption_sdk
import fnmatch
## Initialize the Parameters
def initconfig(input):

    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read_file(open( 'CONFIG_AIRBILLING.conf'))
    print('Code Name is :'+ input)
    global REMOTE_DIR,ACCESS_KEY_ID,ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,BUCKET_NAME,TARGET_DIR,FILENAME,SRC_DIR,FILEPATH
    ACCESS_KEY_ID = config.get('ACCESS', 'ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    print('ACCESS_ID_IS:'+ ACCESS_KEY_ID)
    ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = config.get('ACCESS', 'ACCESS_SECRET_KEY')
    BUCKET_NAME = config.get('ACCESS', 'BUCKET_NAME')
    SRC_DIR = config.get(input, 'SRC_DIR')
    FILENAME = config.get(input, 'FILENAME')
   # FILENAME=FILENAME+'*.txt'
    FILEPATH=SRC_DIR+'\\'+FILENAME
    print('File Path is:'+FILEPATH)
    TARGET_DIR = config.get(input, 'TARGET_DIR')


## This function will make sure file exist in Source directory
def readstatus():


      for file in os.listdir(SRC_DIR):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file,FILENAME+'*.txt'):
            result='True'
            print('****'+file)
            movefiles(file)



## This function will move the files to AWS S3 bucket
def movefiles(result):

    s3 = boto3.resource(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
        config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
    )
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key=TARGET_DIR + '/' + result, Body=result)
    print('***File Moved***')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    initconfig(sys.argv[1])
    readstatus()
```

Comment: If you're interested in the _raising_ itself, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36077266/how-do-i-raise-a-filenotfounderror-properly.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

The snippet below filters the list of files in the `SRC_DIR` using the `fnmatch` and pattern, and returns the list. Then, it checks if the list is empty, i.e. no files matching the pattern were found, it raises an `Exception`. Otherwise, it goes on ahead processing the individual files.

```
def readstatus():
  files = list(filter(lambda f: fnmatch.fnmatch(f, FILENAME+"*.txt"), os.listdir(SRC_DIR)))
  if not files:
    raise Exception("Files matching pattern not found!")
  for file in files:
    print(f"***{file}")
    movefiles(file)
```

In case the file is not found, you could expect an error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
    readstatus()
  File "main.py", line 10, in readstatus
    raise Exception("Files matching pattern not found!")
Exception: Files matching pattern not found!
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

**TRY:**

```
def readstatus():
    result = False
    for file in os.listdir(SRC_DIR):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, FILENAME + '*.txt'):
            result = True
            print('****' + file)
            movefiles(file)

    if result != True:
        print("your file doesn't exist")
        #add exception logic here
```

The Logic is that if the file is matched with the given filename, then result variable will be `True`, otherwise the `result` variable will be `False`.

We use the value of the variable `result` as a checksum for whether the file existed or not.

Comment: A more pythonic way would be using `try: except:` clauses. This is exactly what they're intended for.

Comment: additionally why are you using the strings `'True'` and `'False'` instead of the constants `True` and `False`?

Comment: @smallpants the problem with using `try except` clause is that, except only gets executed upon an error, but with the `fnmatch.fnmatch()` no error occurs even if the files do not match, so instead of creating a logic for raising an exception, why not simply use an `if else`? Atleast this is my perspective towards this. Alternatively he can create exception's inside the `if` clause too if he wants that.

Comment: Thank you Vasu Deo, Adam and smallpants.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3.4+, consider using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to make a lot of these pains easier.

```py
def readstatus():

    root = pathlib.Path(SRC_DIR)
    for fpath in root.glob(f"{FILENAME}*.txt"):
        movefiles(str(fpath))
```