# raise an exception with the name of the file that is missing

Tags: python

I want to raise an exception with the name of the file that is missing:

```
f1 = Path(DIR_PATH, "one.txt").resolve()
f2 = Path(DIR_PATH, "two.txt").resolve()

# 1 Is there a way of doing this?
if not f1.exists() or not f2.exists():
    raise Exception(f"The file {?} does not exist")

# 2 instead of this
if not f1.exists():
    raise Exception(f"The file {f1} does not exist")
elif not f2.exists():
    raise Exception(f"The file {f2} does not exist")
```

Is there a way of doing #1 rather than #2 from the above code?

Comment: Is there a specific reason (rather than mere curiosity) for using #1 instead of #2?

Comment: @DYZ It is curiosity and less code if it was possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could run a loop over the files:

```
for fn in [f1, f2]:
    if not fn.exists():
        raise Exception(f"The file {fn} does not exist")
```

For only two files, this is one line shorter than your option #2, but if you have more files this will be much more compact than a series of `if` statements.

As pointed out by @tdelaney, it would be better to raise a specific error instead of using the generic `Exception`. A more appropriate one is [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError), which is called with a number of arguments as explained in [this answer from Martjin Peters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36077407/7517724):

```
import os
import errno

for fn in [f1, f2]:
    if not fn.exists():
        raise OSError(errno.ENOENT, os.strerror(errno.ENOENT), fn)
```

Specifying the error code `errno.ENOENT`, will raise the `FileNotFoundError` subclass of `OSError`, the same error you would get if you tried to open a non-existent file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'one.txt'
```

Comment: I like this except how about `OSError`?

Comment: This is good.  I have several files so this will do the Job.

Comment: @tdelaney As in, try to open the file and it will raise `OSError` automatically, or raise `OSError` instead of a generic exception? I was following the OP's pattern assuming that they had a reason for raising a generic exception.

Comment: @Craig, since a generic `Exception` is almost always a bad idea, I thought it would be nice if your example fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to implicitly determine which proposition in disjunction is `True`.

Comment: I guess it is the most detailed answer to such a question XD